# Modifying content in file

Tags: javascript, node.js

I run into a problem, which I cant solve.

Im making an app, where on the first page I need to choose one of two machines, there are 2 buttons on page and when one of them is clicked, i make POST to /mechineChoose where I pass id of selected machine. Then I need to change config.js file, where I have all params needed for rest of app.

```
const config = {
machineName: "Machine",
...
```

So in my code I need to change machineName, right now I use fs module to read and then write to file, but problem is that I cant change this name more than once. When I restart app, Im able to change the name, but when trying to choose second machine, nothing happens.

```
router.post("/machineChoose", async (req, res) => {
console.log(req.body.machineChoose);
if (req.body.machineChoose == 1) {
    machineX = "Machine1";

} else {
    machineX = "Machine2";
}
console.log(machineX);
fs.readFile('./config.js', 'utf-8', function (err,data){
    if (err){
        console.log(err);
    }
    var result = data.replace(config.machineName,machineX);
    fs.writeFileSync('./config.js', result, 'utf-8', function(err){
        if (err) return console.log(err);
    });
});
return res.send("")
```

})

Any idea how to solve it ?

Comment: Probably has nothing to do with your problem but 1) what is `fs.close;` supposed to do? 2) why do you use the callback based version of `fs.readFile` in an `async` context? 3) why do you use `fs.writeFileSync` in an `async` context

Comment: fs.close() shouldnt be there, i just forget to delete it, and fswriteFileSync should be fs.writeFile, same thing, forgot to change it, I just tried other stuff and forgot to change, but changing it back to fs.writeFile, doesnt work either

Comment: Well, once you've overwritten the machineName-field with e.g. `"Machine1"`, further calls to `data.replace` will not replace anything, since it still will be called with `"Machine"`. Should the content of `config.js` always match the content of `const config = {...}`?

Comment: const config = {...} is inside config.js file, so I wanted to change name of machine inside this file

Comment: Yes, but you load it into memory at some point right? Or where does the `config` object come from that you use in `data.replace(config.machineName, ...)` ?

Comment: Its loaded when starting app, but idea is to choose machine and then login to app and there will be smth like heading with name of picked at start machine, which is read from this config file.

Answer (score 0):

After writing to the file, you need to reload the `config`-object as it will still hold the previous state in-memory and thus further calls to `data.replace(...)` will not replace anything, since it will still be called with "Machine".

I would do something like this (although you should consider using a real database):

```
router.post("/machineChoose", async (req, res) => {
    const chosenMachine = req.body.machineChoose == 1 ? "Machine1" : "Machine2";
    const config = await readConfig();
    config.machineName = chosenMachine;
    await writeConfig(config);
    res.status(204).end();
});

async function writeConfig(currentConfig) {
    try {
        await fs.promises.writeFile("./config.json", JSON.stringify(currentConfig));
    } catch (e) {
        console.log("Could not write config file", e)
        throw e;
    }
}

async function readConfig() {
    try {
        const rawConfig = await fs.promises.readFile("./config.json", {encoding: 'utf-8'});
        return JSON.parse(rawConfig);
    } catch (e) {
        console.log("Could not read config file", e)
        throw e;
    }
}
```

Comment: Using your example gives me this error when choosing machine: `undefined:1
const config = {
^

SyntaxError: Unexpected token c in JSON at position 0`

Comment: Try saving the file with actual json content. Remove `const config = ` and just save the actual json-object with `{ "machineName": "Machine" }`

Comment: I cant do that, because in this file I have config and im exporting this `const config={}`, at the end i have: `module.export = config` so i belive it is repsponsible for this error